# What is different between JsonObject and JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

What is different between JsonObject and JSONObject?

I am little bit confuse JsonObject and JSONObject and when we use put, add and addproperty method.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the import statements... They are different libraries

Comment: This isnt base Java, those are Objects depending on the JSON-libary you are using.

Comment: there is nothing called JsonObject unless you created it as a new class in your project

Comment: @Haidar Or Gson..  https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html

Comment: JSONObject is "native" to Android SDK, JsonObject is probably the one from Gson library, the one that I use. Two different package, don't work with both ;) choose one. I had some issue with the date formatting in JSONObject.

Comment: @cricket_007 i didn`t know thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Android SDK provides `JSONObject`. This can be used by importing `org.json.JSONObject`.

The documentation for JSONObject is [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html).

Any other variant will be from a library or linked project. The exmaple given by cricket_007 is `JsonObject` from the Gson libraries. This can be used by importing `com.google.gson.JsonObject`.

The documentation for JsonObject is [here](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html).

Note the difference in import statement for `JSONObject` and `JsonObject` - they are different classes in different packages. They can have different methods and functionality, take different parameters etc, but ultimately they will do the same or similar thing (holding a Json Object's contents). It is up to you which you use. The JavaDoc for each will describe how to use it, and there are plenty of resources online for each.