# JsonObject vs JSONObject

Tags: java, json, oracle

I am a bit confused about Json Class in java libraries.
I could find these 3 at least and all seems Oracle Json Libraries

- javax.json [JsonObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html)
- com.oracle.json [JsonObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javame/8.0/api/json/api/com/oracle/json/JsonObject.html)
- org.json [JSONObject](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Why so many Oracle json class?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38569748/9280565 Detail explanation about two Libraries atleat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I could find these 3 at least and all seems Oracle Json Libraries

Actually, there are many more than that; see the list at https://www.json.org/json-en.html.  Many are not Oracle classes.   Indeed `org.json.JSONObject` is not an Oracle class.

> Why so many Oracle json class?

History.  It took a long time for Oracle to include JSON support in the official Java libraries.  And by the time that they did, various other people / organizations had produced their own offerings, and developed their own followings.

(The reason the Oracle have two JSON implementations is that their design goals are significantly different.)

> Which one is the recommended one and why?

There is no single recommendation.  It very much depends on what your application requires in terms of JSON support.  Do you want something light-weight?  Do you need to fit in with an existing framework (e.g. Java EE or Java ME)?  Do you need POJO "bindings"?  Streaming parsers?

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing up a lot of things here.

`javax.json` is part of the [JSON-B](https://javaee.github.io/jsonb-spec/) and [JSON-P](https://javaee.github.io/jsonp/) Java EE API - used for JSON processing and data binding. And used in context of an application server (`WildFly` / `Tomcat` / ...)

whereas `com.oracle.json` refers to [Java ME ("Micro Edition")](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javameoverview.html).

and `org.json` is just another parser, like GSON.

You wouldn't use `com.oracle.json` outside of a Java ME environment, but whether you use `javax.json`, `org.json`, `GSON`, `Jackson`, ... is up to your personal taste and requirements. But mostly, the application server already contains a JSON parser - for `Wildfly`, this was `Jackson` until `JSON-B/P` arrived rather late to the parsing party.